# How do I make DispatchGroup work consequently with DispatchQueue?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two ViewControllers, first one is for showing news, the second one is for choosing news sources which will be shown in first VC.
This is the code I use for fetching news inside FeedViewController.

```
@objc private func fetchData() {
    articles = []
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for source in MediaSourceManager.shared.getMediaSources(coreDataStack: coreDataStack) {
        if source.isSelected {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            FeedAPI.shared.getArticles(newsSource: source) { (articles) in
                self.articles += articles
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In getArticles it's just a URLSession.shared.dataTask request.

In MediaSourceManager I have

```
private let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "News.mediaQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

private var unsafeSources: [MediaSource] = []

var safeSources: [MediaSource] {
    var mediasCopy: [MediaSource]!
    concurrentQueue.sync {
        mediasCopy = self.unsafeSources
    }

    return mediasCopy
}

func changeSourceIsSelected(at index: Int) {
    concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.unsafeSources[index].isSelected = !self.unsafeSources[index].isSelected
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.postSelectionNotification()
        }
    }
}
```

The code in postSelectionNotification

```
private func postSelectionNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .mediaSelectedChanged, object: nil)
}
```

In a getArticles, I convert every article description from html string to normal string, and it seems like a heavy task. So I am having errors like index out of range and weird behavior like articles which source I removed still be shown, it happens if I am doing everything fast in a UI(choosing various media sources and moving fast to the feed screen). How can I fix this?

Comment: How many articles are you fetching? If you are fetching a bunch of articles, consider using pagination. Also, how are those 2 view controllers related? Is one the master, one the detail?  (i.e., they are showing at the same time on iPad) If you can add more code for context, that would be great.

Comment: @rs7 40 articles from a source, and there are six different source for now. Those are two different VC's in a tab bar.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Can you add the code for postSelectionNotification? How is it notifying the FeedViewController, and what method is at the other end of that notification and what does that method do?

Comment: @rs7 It just posts notification and I add an observer in viewDidLoad of FeedVC, which calls fetch method(first part of attached code).

Comment: Can you also add the code for the function the notification triggers?

Comment: @rs7 It's fetchData(). I've changed the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most optimal way to tackle this, but I'll share my approach nonetheless. First, inside FeedViewController, add a variable count that will keep track of the number of requests being processed, and a UIActivityIndicator. Make sure when your activity indicator is running, userInteraction is disabled for FeedViewController.

```
@objc private func fetchData() {
    articles = []
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    count += 1 // This variable is to keep track of the number of requests being run
    if !activityIndicator.isAnimating { activityIndicator.startAnimating() }
    for source in MediaSourceManager.shared.getMediaSources(coreDataStack: coreDataStack) {
        if source.isSelected {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            FeedAPI.shared.getArticles(newsSource: source) { (articles) in
                self.articles += articles
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        self.count -= 1
        if self.count == 0 {
             self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
             self.feedTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

If I can think of a better solution, I'll update my answer.